# Превьюшка PDF с помощью ImageMagick (convert): откуда шум?

Tags: centos, pdf, imagemagick

Задача - на лету создавать превьюхи для PDF. Запускаю convert под CentOS:    convert test.pdf[0] -resize 640x640 test.jpgНа выходе получается много шума, например:[image]От значений -resize и выходного формата ничего не зависит, от исходных PDF тоже. Чего ему не хватает?

Answer (score 1):

`-resize` уберите! Надо бы вот так:

```
convert -thumbnail 640x640 test.pdf test.png
```

Comment: А почему .png? Да потому, что он лучше для тамнейлов!